# RegEx for links except images, scripts etc

Tags: html, regex

I wrote a regex that finds all links in the text.

```
(?s)(?m)(?i).*(http://[0-9a-z.%/_-]+).?".*
```

How to except the references to images, scripts, etc.?

Comment: The regular expression won't work at all. You need to escape characters like `/` with backslashes: `http://` becomes `http:\/\/`. Also this would match things like `http://%%%%%%.....______----` which simply isn't valid.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly depends on the language and the use of delimiters :)

Comment: @far_outer you might use `(?smi)` to set the modifiers. I'm wondering what do you mean by this sentence `How to except the references to images, scripts, etc.?` ? Can you please explain it a bit further and show some examples what should be matched and what not ?

Comment: Which language do you use ?

Comment: @HamZa I use Java.
examples:
http://www.oracle.com/javaone/index.html - matched
http://education.oracle.com/ - matched
http://search.oracle.com/search/search - matched 
http://www.oracleimg.com/us/assets/metrics/ora_ocom.js - not matched
http://www.oracleimg.com/us/assets/metrics/ora.jpg - not matched

Comment: @far_outer: You can never tell whether the link is to an image/script or not. The server can be configured to return something unexpected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one is messy, but get's the job done:

```
(?!https?:\/\/[\w%\/_.-]+\.(jpg|js|gif))(https?:\/\/[\w%\/_.-]+\.\w+)
```

It's a negative look ahead to rule out unwanted links, followed by a "all links" capture. Maybe not the most elegant solution, but it works.

Also allows https. Add unwanted link types to the (jpg|js|gif) list (separated by vertical bar).

I'm not sure about java, but it works in flavours [regex101](http://regex101.com/r/tO7vO2) offers. Use global flag.

Comment: UPDATE : (?!https?:\/\/[\w%\/_.-]+\.(jpg|js|gif))(https?:\/\/[\w%\/_.-]+\.[\w%\/_.-]+)

Comment: @SujithPS: Forgot about the "default document" link. Nice